# I can't get Ubuntu installation to start

Tags: installation, boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I have a computer with the following configuration:

- AZUS Sabertooth Motherboard
- Intel I5 2500 CPU
- Windows 7 installed

I'm trying to install linux. I first attempted to install pin guy. I burned the ISO, booted from it, got the initial menu; attempting to either run the live version from DVD, or install to system. However the process stops at a blank screen with the blinking cursor in left corner.

So I downloaded Ubuntu and got the same results. Then I tried wubi and ended up in the same position.

**EDIT**: UEFI might be part of the problem?  Based on the link below I have determined that the process will be too time consuming and or risky so I'm giving up.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFIBooting

Comment: Try the [Alternate Install 32bit](http://mirror01.th.ifl.net/releases/precise/ubuntu-12.04.1-alternate-i386.iso) or [Alternate Install 64bit](http://mirror01.th.ifl.net/releases/precise/ubuntu-12.04.1-alternate-amd64.iso).

Answer (score 0):

Please visit the link https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/amd64/boot-troubleshooting.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.